# selenium add_cookie needs two requests

Tags: python, selenium, cookies

I'm passing a session login cookie in a test:

```
def test_2_has_session(self):
        """Authenticated user gets admin page"""
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get(BaseTest.base_cms_url)
        self.set_session_cookies(driver)
        driver.get(BaseTest.base_cms_url)
        assert "Site administration" in driver.title
```

The above works. But the only way I can get it to work, is using that weird "get the page, set the cookie, get the page again" process. If I call my `set_session_cookies()` function (which just calls `driver.add_cookie()`) *before* `driver.get()`, no dice: the request doesn't pass the cookie and the test receives a login page response. If I call it *after*, I get the same login page response. Only if I call the page, set the cookie, then call the page again, then the test get a logged-in page as a response.

The [docs](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html#cookies) aren't exactly helpful in explaining why I should need to do this. What am I missing?

Comment: The docs you linked clearly mention `you need to be on the domain that the cookie will be valid for`. As for the second call does refreshing the page works? sometimes it necessary.

Comment: If I follow the example in the docs, which does `driver.get()` followed by `driver.add_cookie()`, then the result is not what I'd expect: the page returned is a login prompt, indicating that the site didn't receive a valid session cookie with the request. It's got nothing to do with "being on" the correct domain: why, if I call `add_cookie()` followed by `get()`, is the cookie I've just added not included with the request?

Comment: You have to be in the domain to add the cookies. Acording to the example you don't need to use the second 'get', but in my experience you need to atleast refresh the page for the cookie to stick.